# Set the maximum number of rows in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to draw several datasets within a single plot. The number of datasets varies, so I don't know a priori how many there will be.

If I just draw the legends, I get this (MCVE below):

[image]

How can I tell `plt.legend()` to only draw say the first 10 legends? I've looked around the [plt.legends()](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/legend_api.html) class but there seems to be no argument to set such a value.

*MCVE*:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = []
for _ in range(20):
    dataset.append(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 2))

lbl = ['adfg', 'dfgb', 'cgfg', 'rtbd', 'etryt', 'frty', 'jklg', 'jklh',
       'ijkl', 'dfgj', 'kbnm', 'bnmbl', 'qweqw', 'fghfn', 'dfg', 'hjt', 'dfb',
       'sdgdas', 'werwe', 'dghfg']

for i, xy in enumerate(dataset):
    plt.scatter(xy[0], xy[1], label=lbl[i])
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: I don't know the correct way to do it but a possible workaround might be to put an if statement in your for loop and only use `label=` if `_` is less than 10?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. That is indeed a workaround, but I was wondering if there might be a less "hackish" way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just limit the number of labels shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maxn = 16
for i in range(25):
    plt.scatter(.5, .5, label=(i//maxn)*"_"+str(i))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

This method works also for text labels of course:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ["".join(np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJK"), size=8)) for k in range(25)]
maxn = 16
for i,l in enumerate(labels):
    plt.scatter(.5, .5, label=(i//maxn)*"_"+l)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The reason this works is that labels starting with `"_"` are ignored in the legend. This is used internally to give objects a label without showing them in the legend but can of course also be used by us to limit the number of elements in the legend.

Comment: This only seems to work if the labels are the numbers `i`, which is not the case. It's my fault, I oversimplified my MCVE. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @Gabriel even if your labels are not numbers, you can keep a dynamically build a label list and use this method to select the index of that label list to show the output

Comment: Excellent, it indeed works! Could you explain why prepending a `_` to the label prevents it from showing? I was not aware of this feature.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest an alternative way to get your desired output, which I feel relies less on a "hack" of the legend labels.

You can use the [function `Axes.get_legend_handles_labels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-get-legend-handles-labels) to get a list of the handles and the labels of the objects that are to be put in the legend.
You can truncate these lists however you feel like, before passing them to `plt.legend()`. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = []
for _ in range(20):
    dataset.append(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 2))

lbl = ['adfg', 'dfgb', 'cgfg', 'rtbd', 'etryt', 'frty', 'jklg', 'jklh',
       'ijkl', 'dfgj', 'kbnm', 'bnmbl', 'qweqw', 'fghfn', 'dfg', 'hjt', 'dfb',
       'sdgdas', 'werwe', 'dghfg']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, xy in enumerate(dataset):
    ax.scatter(xy[0], xy[1], label=lbl[i])

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(h[:3], l[:3])   # <<<<<<<< This is where the magic happens
plt.show()
```

You could even display every other label `plt.legend(h[::2], l[::2])` or whatever else you want.